# Django dict in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access some data in a template. I don't think the way I'm doing it now is the best way, but I can't get it even half working any other way.

```
def room(request, room_id):
        #get room data
        room = Room.objects.filter(id=room_id).get()
        modules = []
        #pull all actuator devices for the room
        actuators = Device.objects.filter(room_id=room_id,type="actuator")
        #build a list of modules then use set to remove duplicates
        for actuator in actuators.values():
                module = Module.objects.get(module_id=actuator["module_id"]).name_only()
                modules.extend([module])
        modlist = list(set(modules))
        moduleData = {}
        #loop through the modules, pull out the required data and send it all off to the template
        for module in modlist:
                data = Module_List.objects.get(name=module)
                dict = {"name": data.name, "widget_mqtt_js": data.widget_mqtt_js, "widget_setup_js": data.widget_setup_js, "widget_body": data.widget_body}
                moduleData[module] = dict
                print dict["widget_mqtt_js"]
        context = {"room_name" : room.name, "actuators" : actuators, "modules" : moduleData}
        return render(request, 'control/room.html', context)
```

This is my code as it stands. The problem I'm having is that the loop in my template is returning blank. It looks like this:

```
 {% for module in modules %}
     {{module.widget_mqtt_js}}
 {% endfor %}
```

I think there will be a way to do it with the Module_List model, but I could't get that working either..

Comment: `module` here is the each iterated key of `modules`. Use `{% for module_name, module in modules.iteritems %}` to access values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`modules` in the template context is `moduleData` in your view code. But `moduleData` is a `dict`, and iterating over a `dict` yields its keys, not its values.

You need to iterate over the values, try:

```
{% for module in modules.values %}
    {{module.widget_mqtt_js}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sweet that got it to show up. Can you tell me how to stop it from being HTML escaped? For example I'm getting &quot; instead of " etc

Comment: @Dan Are you sure this is desirable? Bear in mind that disabling escaping can facilitate XSS attacks. If you do know what you're doing, then this is how you do it: `{{module.widget_mqtt_js|safe}}`, using the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) template filter.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Orozco, yes I'm sure, as it's inserting JS stored in a database as part of a module.